# React AgGrid Server Side Datasource getRows fires only once, scroll not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have created AgGrid using AgGridReact component, set server side datasource using examples from documentation but somehow infinite scroll is not working. getRows function is called only on the initial render and no scrollbar is shown on the grid.

```
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react';
import {
  AllModules,
  ColumnApi,
  GridReadyEvent,
  IServerSideGetRowsParams,
  ModelUpdatedEvent,
  GridApi,
  ColDef,
  ToolPanelVisibleChangedEvent,
} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';

export const DataGrid = <T extends unknown>({ rows, columns, onRowsFetch }: React.PropsWithChildren<Props<T>>) => {
  const gridApi = useRef<GridApi>();
  const gridColumnApi = useRef<ColumnApi>();

  return (
    <Box height="800px" width="100%" boxSizing="border-box" className="ag-theme-material">
      <AgGridReact
        modules={AllModules}
        popupParent={document.body}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        headerHeight={90}
        rowData={rows}
        rowModelType={onRowsFetch ? 'serverSide' : 'clientSide'}
        serverSideDatasource={{ getRows }}
        cacheBlockSize={100}
        blockLoadDebounceMillis={500}
        maxBlocksInCache={100}
        suppressContextMenu
        colResizeDefault="shift"
        columnDefs={columns as ColDef[]}
        columnTypes={columnTypes.reduce((ac, a) => ({ ...ac, [a]: {} }), {})}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        onModelUpdated={resizeColumns}
        onGridSizeChanged={resizeColumns}
        onToolPanelVisibleChanged={resizeColumns}
        suppressMovableColumns
        suppressColumnMoveAnimation
        sideBar={sideBarDef}
        suppressMenuHide
        alwaysShowVerticalScroll
      />
    </Box>
  );

  function onGridReady({ api, columnApi }: GridReadyEvent) {
    gridApi.current = api;
    gridColumnApi.current = columnApi;
    api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    api.setFilterModel({});
  }

  function resizeColumns({ api }: ModelUpdatedEvent | ToolPanelVisibleChangedEvent) {
    api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }

  async function getRows({ request, successCallback, failCallback }: IServerSideGetRowsParams) {
    if (!onRowsFetch) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const result = await onRowsFetch({
        startRow: request.startRow,
        endRow: request.endRow,
        sort: parseSortModel(request.sortModel),
        filter: parseFilterModel(request.filterModel),
      });
      successCallback(result.content, result.endRow ?? -1);
    } catch (error) {
      failCallback();
      throw error;
    }
  }
};
```

Request to the api does not include startRow and endRow parameters (getRows function's `params` argument's props request.startRow and request.endRow somehow are undefined).

However, api request still returns with this response:

```json
{
  content: [...rowData],
  endRow: 10,
  lastRow: 474,
  startRow: 0,
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there were no issues with the code. The problem was in the version of the ag-grid packages. I've downgraded it from `v25.3` to `v24.1` and now everything works as expected.

Comment: Since 25.0 ag-grid team make some changes in server-side row model. You can read about it here https://blog.ag-grid.com/upgrading-to-ag-grid-v25-server-side-row-model/

Comment: @AntonDikarev I have upgraded to v25.3, changed `serverSideStoreType` to `Partial` and `successCallback` to `success` just as mentioned in this article, but now my data does not stop loading - it keeps firing requests for rowData every second and the table just keeps showing `Loading...`. Did I miss something?

Comment: It happens no matter what number I put in `success({ rowCount })` parameter.